# How do I define an array's size when the class is created?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I want to create an array contained inside of a class. The array **will** be of fixed size, but I don't know that fixed size until the constructor of the class.

Let's say the users create something like: `Fibanocci f(value1, value2, size)`. The `size` argument would then used to determine the number of elements in the containing array, which will be fixed throughout the *entire* life of the `Fibanocci` instance.

How do I pull this off?

Comment: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Even if the array's sized is going to be fixed throughout the _entire_ life of the classes instance? The amount of memory that needs allocated will still be fixed.

Comment: @IQAndreas Yes, just use `reserve(size)` in the constructor and you're good to go.

Comment: The size is still a run-time variable, so it can't be set during compilation (which is needed for `std::array` and old C-style arrays). Therefore `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Go with `std::vector<type> vector` instead and you can do `int size = vector.size()`. You can initialize the size of the vector in the constructor. For example,

```cpp
// MyClass.hpp
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();

    // Say I know this vector is going to have 5 elements
    std::vector<double> myVector; 
}

// MyClass.cpp
MyClass::MyClass() : myVector(5)
{
    int vectorSize = myVector.size(); //vectorSize = 5
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Array size must be known at compile-time!! Don't think you will lose performance by using vector, it's a wrapper over array. If you are really stringent and have C++11, you can use array from the standard library.

**Do I use resize or reserve?**

Reserve will allocate memory but not insert anything. Resize will insert copies of default-constructed objects, unless you specify a parameter.

Comment: `std::array` does not support runtime-determined size.

Comment: Where in my answer did I say any of those things?

Comment: You said you can use std::array.

Comment: std::array is not suitable at all, since its size (that is template argument) should be known at compile time too.

Answer (score -3):

Java makes the array dynamic it will assign size at run time.
Proxy class will form whose object is this array.

```
int a[]=new int[10];
```

Comment: this question is not about java